# Easy way to query a table and map to pojo

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc, spring-data

I am having trouble finding the simplest way to run a select * statement against my oracle database. All I want to do is see if one of the fields in the table is ON or OFF and then perfom some validations. My application is build on Spring Boot but I know there are several ways to query a table and map the values to some pojo. I have jdbc connection details in my application.properties

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty straight forward. You have not displayed any code structure or other information, so I am taking the liberty of assuming a few things.

Firstly, I believe that you launcher class has the required configurations like oracle data source provider bean

```
@Bean(name = "dataSource")
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
public OracleDataSource oracleDataSource() throws SQLException {
    OracleDataSource dataSource = new OracleDataSource();
    dataSource.setUser(userName);
    dataSource.setPassword(password);
    dataSource.setURL(dataSourceUrl);
    dataSource.setImplicitCachingEnabled(true);
    dataSource.setFastConnectionFailoverEnabled(true);
    dataSource.setDriverType(driverClass);

    return dataSource;
}
```

The property file will have the required connection details, so i believe you have referenced the required variables from the property files to the corresponding username, password strings.

Once you have this sorted, you need to create the required DAO and entity classes.

Create a DAO package, preferably an interface

```
@Repository
public interface YourDao {
    List<SampleClass> getRowsfromDB(String foobar) throws exception

    }
```

Your SampleClass is your entity POJO

```
@Table(name = "TABLE_NAME")
public class SampleClass implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 175721653757515959L;

@Id
@Column(name = "COL1")
private Long columnOne;


@Column(name = "COL2")
private String column2;

...generate getters and setters
}
```

After you have done this, create a typed query in DAO IMPL class. Its is a simple method you can get by googling.

If this is the direction you are looking, let me know if you need more help on this.

Answer (score 0):

**I think you can do something like this:**

```
public interface UserDataRepository extends JpaRepository<UserData, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT flag FROM user_data", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<Object[]> findFlags();
}

System.out.println("data"+  userDataRepository.findFlags());
```

**Hope this helps!**